# Encoding and Decoding bin file

Tags: java, android, encoding, base64, decoding

I have seen so many examples online but they are not exactly what Im looking for.

I have a .bin file that I'd like to POST to a server, so I am encoding and storing it as a string.

However, decoding it doesn't give the same result.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

File file = getFileStreamPath(ENROLL_FILENAME);
byte[] bytes = loadFile(file);
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);

for(int i =0; i< encoded.length; i++){
    System.out.print(encoded[i]);
}
System.out.println();

String encodedString = new String(encoded); //send to sever and decode
System.out.println("Encode "+ encodedString);

byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedString.getBytes());
for(int i =0; i< decoded.length; i++){
    System.out.print(decoded[i]);
}
System.out.println();
```

Result:

```
System.out: 1147948656688781216567661069850481179071904876109571171018810311782109108117905086121997274112981108285908749119987170489081656565656565656565666511965678710365769951100112904878789087498010050537565651041221005010811081496648991101041191011036565666565656567122119891035265658065115656565686565656511081736565757366656565706565656565656565656565656565661016881656583857712010311971576582896765119491017310369786574119798181658665676580886569866574107788465658765661038082119698965748977756569906573119781148169976580115751026569986577657448103659965736578886569996566697811610369102657273755310365103656548781181036510465658579104656910565777374122119651086565527811281691086572107707165691106565119794365651126573897855656511465651157790656911465746979791196911865668178103816911965795675656569122656669787465691226566107795511965496574737768103694965668179841036550657473798811965516566103808465695365747778108119695365806573104816554656511580102656954656681759010369576566567886119666665737379831197066656765789711966686574103805211966736573111809065707665678979101103668165666980115103708365785677856570886567997970816697657289789011966976573858011381709965767378838166102656510779708166103656910778791196610465651077885817010465686580741036610665801117610265701096568657779103701146575698080656611565678178861196611565668979119103661156565119801001196611665737378107119661166573568097816612065658178978170122656885801121197050657665791081196653657248789065665565655276102119665565731077767103705665686980103817043657673801038167676580103777011971676568858011465717165688579122816772657399785011967776574737810211971776568103791068171806576997953119678265705278571036783656948808910371836568568010311967856573817610981718965699977100119679065805277111657197656973771161036798657377781161036710465801197811410371109656965797665671126566898085816711265756580108657111565778178791037111765777380106656712065657378102817112165698979110119711226577737869656756656777801066567476565103791101036865656565781148168656572737789103726665778980100816867656665805565686965711118011781687065738978120816872657252784881687665727780110816878657356791076572786577857976119688165655280114817281656969767711972876570111809711968906573103751011196890657369768481689965731157811365689965721118010211972996577107808010372104657873808511968106657277781081196810665728579116103721086574487376103681096567111798811968109657211177801036811265714879701196811365688980891197211765781038010110368118657156771076572118657077751001197248657811579731036851657552797910368536579107791141197257656910373821036843658069797065724765796580578165676510185801066569686585697487816971651018179901196972658611179761036574651004879114816977651006977688269817268798174105756874476571675081737353717976897773778950101661211017370876968701201077373101479067431225273759771741127765767454877010184577010275707110654677250107756897721197086101657110611212272821005267112113746811643677411652767511848536757514370118102827283103118721196711567854912170651041227088905572104864966121575269901176570102100557371538267113785169111685375727567771111211196890566770739772708011778705478556989885170887170757211452765284546749115676810310284718111711772117768367844379691021197471711076672110111686811770436911810772101103656566656589897310710410555998210880778212210210386865265985210211577995111578725185808680818510688107751138810777981118578731025287104102111821095265837551738811110210399871185285103111698853102115891064781978172527653781157987105488783675689111102567870731157910010248825411056874711989826611948875211985888965859776894875111111998012165119825489698782811037956103778282811038797801159065735279691046582568811110347471111031147211178120748982105736582545289107110537773771107785103515697565181995065738973656989978899986857119101786752901218011199547277109438077115497389768012185875347859079867398971218179112471078372895287886511597535211978501091117911111865856511711110174474873748948881084710789651191199899801118210573658566899985986689887612077871221021031011191105610751881071081
System.out: Encode 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
System.out: -84-19051151140329911110946100102116461111101211204670105110103101114112114105110116841011091121089711610100000001302900111151191051036777101109791191107408115119105103678011611412011212200400044-16981400-1644003000-99200-94100500000000000941300736749-1251-67122231394341130-100146502103215921210-103137602202415711240-10612401250-11613-831260-5101241270-649-460280-128139212801713-74131011410-2603201313-660330514-1241340-629-4903701413-91137012152413901214-80410-12213-20043011121001430-111145914702013-1271480-17100151017133615102514-170530-110121415302014780540-110149505502415761570-10913-1051570-168-123058011151241580201010216103113870650-1261475165032131070670-10415-290720-118151001750381412208001715-781820-33128018703914210900118131030900-12315-871920-781373095091421096073135909709138119704815380990-6111241102048125811070-95156001080361387010802214-6201080121511901090-12613-10901090-1131510501130413105111505315-8911180-8014-105012101251310001230141112701230-1191210112404915-12711260-7815-1270-1260-812231-12605315-841-12205314-510-1210-12113-370-1160-110131271-11605614-1151-1130-7314-250-11109413-100-11007715981-11006315-1250-1080-12411-1031-104071121190-1030-212-961-10206612-740-1010-12513-740-950-413-821-9006414440-8702215810-870-9615-1081-840-6013581-820-6215-1160-7902131251-7807014-971-770-6213160-6803515-1160-650814-980-640013-830-64011412981-630-58151170-6201615-200-60010615-710-590-12213-590-57012613-470-53011515-990-510-11314-1121-510-5914470-4801415-831-4806511511-42090151070-390-120101230-390-12711770-360-11713-880-360122151271-360-5515621-310-4615830-29011513-1050-29011714-741-270-998460-2604214950-26012212620-23010914230-2205415991-180-40151220-17011112-1121-17083101191-120-3714340-90-8214580-70-2314-811-30728700-20-1514201-10-3215-11021-2715-11613165989161-2814103171901446091-3514-831121-47121317162851-1123834-12539-16611100835-111-11445-125849-115-98739-120219732325833-17-3911-20-832-90-12238-109044-98-10621-28-321-14-1232662-126311051013-95-162187-1282658115292312010-102-11914-33-12638-341142-35711-35-222-9-47294047310-8497711420811521118123302111774712017-101-12821-9123321108110-9311918-128-740114-12650-116-8013-97220-122-12120-5-11523-9312317-123-921113-12340122-847-124-611912147-452511-8230-30-46963-11417-4924105130122314-3112618-7712200402496-11933-117-7317-108-1317-51-82187-12827-31-51211512313311171584-1220-11512110-8712112110-1231333-222-123-617-101-128184311423-95-82890-220-126-12723-27-524-113-12266412611-28-3714904522724724-95-11320-11714117-317-2212722-161771322-295239652645-11510-94-12115-561217-23-1272269814-1431769822104-5250-11414181617-1512232-1-632-8412213-60-10617-120-12817-21-12236-97-10985011520-12512726-1311628-40224321241051192715-3630524625-56-628-2411538-8-1344-44-12211633722-25-11255782271073614-89-71829-11422921126-25-11613-3810614-94-16202-223039-3837-11523-105-72431227112-617-120-128205-121201082223471922-51-830-6212736-3512137-5041432723-60-127-22629-73-10201212121-37-1162566629-77-11313-1453764-1738-1947478610210-107-9231672367130-69-122674451930124391810943288221-251162356-12723-62-19248911113-84-452617239123-62421112514-15018-41-2719-106-1330112-1246-9-4517627938566441673711-77-2714113021-131530-122-131012925-65-11329451030106-51713-791926-12421-126-1524-106-4223-72-525-12012636-131038-115-825-5011330-63122427110845-81-12711242718602724-204227921419117181991320-11582472-11129-92-12341-10312245-24-11347-13125151151261641-72344-11824100116133618248862878-105281131311-49-1015113-126197-182357127235152693-12530-27532-108-1017412326-109-23649-7372411013-74-1824115-12324-128-123493-71169102021-82488-11627114-123744-11116-94724-121224-119-1231497-430-83-2841-71-4550-62-97142012221-11-525-122-126269612576111118-6011623541182412012314-35437-71-244251-10850-65-4117-1-12323-95-1326-84-1832-119-11157-112884129-871233092413-252151241128-9694094151414-1221481-1272990-1530-64-7148212715-2911221112522-3311713-78-5215371728-79-4141124515-74-1728-68-69301728373324305773210103742-11542101-713108-12218-72-11625-74-53048-126769515-45-11221-125-1252581713114122258
```

Why are the `byte` arrays not the same?

Comment: I'm not sure of the Base64 class you are using, as http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html doesn't show any static method called encodeBase64() and decodeBase64(). Would you tell us more about that? If you can also show the encoded base64 string you obtain that would help.

Comment: @Shlublu I'm using `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: As you are under Android, you should give a try to the built-in class.

Comment: Also, your first System.out.println() doesn't display the original array but the bytes of the encoded string.

Comment: 'have a .bin file that I'd like to POST to a server, so I am encoding and storing it as a string.'. That is a very bad idea. Better send the file 'as is'. You will have to transport 30% more data using base64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are the same. Note that the first line of your output is the *encoded* bytes, and 114 is the decimal ASCII code for 'r', 79 is the decimal ASCII code for 'O', 48 is the decimal ASCII code for '0' etc., so your first and second lines match and are what I'd expect given your code.

Then when you've decoded the values, the bytes are being sign-extended to ints, so -84 is actually 256 - 84 = 172, -19 is 256 - 19 = 237, 0 is 0, etc., and if you base64 decode the second line using command line tools:

```
$ base64 -d < x.bin | od -tu1 | head -2
0000000 172 237   0   5 115 114   0  32  99 111 109  46 100 102 116  46
0000020 111 110 121 120  46  70 105 110 103 101 114 112 114 105 110 116
```

You'll see things match. So I think everything's fine, it's just how and what you're printing that makes things look wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you print out encoded, encodedString and decoded but not bytes. Can you check bytewise whether your arrays are equal or not?